# How do i expand/simplify this quadratic (or quartic?) equation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I'm having trouble doing the following question, was wondering if anyone was able to lend a hand, would be greatly appreciated as i'm not too sure where to start or how to go about this.

> The general quartic equation is
>
> $$ ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + f = 0, $$
>
> where $a,b,c,d$ and $f$ are real numbers and $a>0$. We suppose the coefficients obey the extra condition that
>
> $$ d = \frac{b(4ac-b^2)}{8a^2}. $$
>
> (c) Expand and simplify $$ \left( \sqrt a\,x^2 + \frac{b}{2\sqrt a}x + \frac{4ac-b^2}{8a\sqrt a} \right)^2.$$

Comment: What you are expected to do in (c) is precisely what it says: multiply out that trinomial, to give nine terms, and then see what cancels.  This is a standalone problem, that will fit into the other parts somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Start with

$$ \left( \sqrt a\,x^2 + \frac{b}{2\sqrt a}x + \frac{4ac-b^2}{8a\sqrt a} \right)^2.$$

and expand.  Then, the coefficient on $x^4$ is

$(\sqrt a)(\sqrt a)=a$

The coefficient on $x^3$ is

$(\sqrt a)\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}\right)+(\sqrt a)\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}\right)=b$

The coefficient on $x^2$ is

$(\sqrt a)\left(\frac{4ac-b^2}{8a\sqrt a}\right)+(\sqrt a)\left(\frac{4ac-b^2}{8a\sqrt a}\right)+\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}\right)\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}\right)=c$

The coefficient on $x^1$ is

$\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}\right)\left(\frac{4ac-b^2}{8a\sqrt a}\right)+\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}\right)\left(\frac{4ac-b^2}{8a\sqrt a}\right)=\frac{b(4ac-b^2)}{8a^2}=d$

by assumption.

The coefficient on $x^0$ is

$\left(  \frac{4ac-b^2}{8a\sqrt a} \right)\left(  \frac{4ac-b^2}{8a\sqrt a} \right)=a\left(\frac{d}{b}\right)^2$

which does not match, in general, the coefficient $f$.  If we impose the second condition that $f=a\left(\frac{d}{b}\right)^2$, then the quartic can be factored as suggested.

Comment: Thankyou! This clears a lot up. Just a follow up question, Using the answer, how would i show that a solution x to the quartic equation is the solution to one of two quadratic equations?

Comment: If you have a proposed solution, you can always test its correctness (or lack thereof) by inserting it back into the original equation and seeing if you obtain an equality.  But to use this method, you must have $d$ and $f$ satisfy the two specified conditions.  Let me know if I can improve this answer.  I just want to give the best answer I can.

Comment: So the solution above can't be inserted into the original equation?

Comment: What solution do you mean?  We have been given another form of a quartic equation - a form that is the square of a quadratic.  And we have shown that the two are equivalent if $d$ and $f$ satisfy the specified conditions.  Make sense?

Comment: I'm just confused becuase the question goes on to ask "Using your answer, show that a solution x to the quartic equation is the solution to one of two quadratic equations"

Comment: Find the solutions to the quadratic equations; just use the quadratic formula.  Then, substitute this back into the original quartic and see if it is a solution.